# How to use maximum select queries in hive

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive

I have two tables `emp` and `dept` in oracle. Have imported it to `hive`. The same structure is in `hive`. I need a query where I can select `max no of empno coloumn in hive`. Can I use `ORDER BY EMPNO` instead of `select max(empno)`?

This is the query for **Oracle Database** that I am using.

```
select a.empno,
       a.ename,
       a.hiredate,
       a.mgr,
       a.job,
       a.sal,
       a.comm,
       a.deptno,
       b.deptno,
       b.dname,
       b.loc   
  from emp2 a, 
       dept1 b 
 where a.deptno=b.deptno 
   and a.empno=(select max(empno) from emp2);
```

How can I select `max empno` in `hive`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the detailed database structure and the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: i have two tables emp and dept in oracle i have imported it to hive.i have same structure in hive. i need a querie where i can select max no of empno coloumn in hive.can i use ORDER BY EMPNO .instead of select max(empno).

Comment: Did you try using it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.empno,a.ename,a.hiredate,a.mgr,
a.job,a.sal,a.comm,a.deptno,b.dname,b.loc   
FROM emp2 a, JOIN dept1 b 
ON (a.deptno=b.deptno )
WHERE a.empno =  max(b.empno)
GROUP BY a.empno,a.ename,a.hiredate,a.mgr,
a.job,a.sal,a.comm,a.deptno,b.dname,b.loc 
;
```